# Do Thermal Cutoff switches exist for temperatures below 50 C?

Tags: switches, protection, thermal, heat-protection, thermal-cutoff

I have been trying to find some passive thermal cutoff switches for a project, but it seems that all of them are for 65 degrees C and up.  Is there another name for lower temperature TCOs?

Any help in finding these would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Generally shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: My appologies, this is my first post to this part of stack exchange.  What made me think of trying here was if there was just another name for them.  For instance, it took me forever to find an off the shelf component to just take multiple different voltages or currents and convert them to 0-10V so that my ADC could read them and not burn.  I tried looking for voltage converters, and a few other names.  Eventually found out that that was called a "signal conditioner".  I was hoping there may have been something like that for lower heat TCOs

Comment: 8 years later, this is a great question not a shopping request at all!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, thermal normally-open and normally-closed switches do exist for temperatures below 50 Centigrade.

For instance, see the catalog of [Thermtrol Corporation](http://web.thermtrol.com/ThermtrolPDF/Thermtrol%20Catalog%20Lo%20Res.pdf), which has several options.

Searching for Thermal Switch on eBay yields [this result](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2x-Thermodisc-Thermal-Switch-Close-45-degree-Active-Circle-Curve-feet-/170776905849) - a Normally Closed thermal cutoff switch for 45 Centigrade, rated for 250 V / 10 A.

A little further digging might yield better options or prices.

Answer (score 0):

Since TCO defines the protection for electronic equipment and I would think 45'C and up could be available in this catagory, it may be that you need to look at 
Thermostats or thermo-coupled pressure switches or electronic switches using thermistors or solid state thermal sensors etc etc.

More details on your application could help define the unstated specs.
Voltage, current, cycle lifetime, environmental rating, sealed, air/liquid, chemical compatibility etc.

If you are looking for say a 40'C inline TCO [image], you you need to ride on some existing demand or have purchasing leverage to ask disti's or OEM's like Cantherm, Honeywell for a custom part for say 100K pc's a yr at 10 cents. (ballpark)